# Why do I get error when ifstream is creating file with string read from keyboard?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am doing exercises from Bjarne Stroustrup's book, *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++*. I am on the first exercise in *Chapter 10*, where it says to write a program that produces the sum of all the numbers in a file of whitespace-separated integers. I based my code below on what's used for Exercise 2 of *Chapter 10.5*. I get an error when the `ifstream` object is created. Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    cout << "Plese enter the input file name: " << endl;
    string iname;
    cin >> iname;
    ifstream ist {iname};
    if (!ist) error("Can't open input file ",iname);

    vector<int> numbers;
    int sum;
    int n;
    while(ist>>n) {
        numbers.push_back(n);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<numbers.size(); ++i) {
        sum += numbers[i];
    }
    cout << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Any input I enter is getting error. I tried myin, myin.txt or any other name. The `error("Can't open input file ",iname);` is from the library created by the author.

I know the file does exist in the same directory with main.cpp and created with TextEdit from Mac using the format for plain text.

Comment: what do you enter as input?

Comment: If the error is can't open a file then the default folder is not the one that you think. Or perhaps you named the file differently from what you typed. Be careful with windows the hiding extensions of known types feature may cause you a few headaches if your files are really named `myfile.txt.txt` and you typed `myfile.txt`

Comment: Any input I enter is getting error. I tried `myin`, `myin.txt` or any other name. The `error("Can't open input file ",iname);` is from the library created by the author.

Comment: Make sure the file exists and you have the file in the working directory! If this is Visual Studio the file probably needs to be in the same folder as the project. If it is some other IDE the default folder is probably the same as the executable.

Comment: @s_diaconu Try ifstream ist( iname.c_str() );

Comment: @s_diaconu Or check whether the file is created in the work/current directory.

Comment: "when ifstream is creating" ...what gave you the impression ifstream would create files here?  ifstream's for reading files.

Comment: ***Any input I enter is getting error. I tried myin, myin.txt or any other name.*** This must be an existing file that you created using some other program like notepad and put in your working directory.

Comment: Yes @drescherjm, this is a file from the same directory with `main.cpp` and created with `TextEdit` from Mac using the format for plain text.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I tried with `ifstream ist( iname.c_str() )` and is the same error.

Comment: It may need to be in the same folder as the executable. You should mention what IDE you use and someone probably can help with that. I don't use macOS so I can't help with this OS related problem.

Comment: @s_diaconu So check what directory is current.

Comment: @drescherjm I should put the OS and IDE in the original questions, but in the rush the fix the issue I forgot.

Comment: Don't write code with TextEdit, use an editor meant for programming (Vim, Emacs, Sublime, Atom, VS Code, ...), or an IDE.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I am using Xcode and I thought that the working directory is the folder where the program is. I tried also to add the file from Xcode, but the same error. I figured out how to find the current directory and placed the file in there and it is working. Good to know for the future. Thanks.

Comment: @molbdnilo I used TextEdit and choose `Format > Make Plain Text` and save `file.txt` and is equivalent to Notepad from Windows, but I think is a matter of choice.

Comment: @s_diaconu Why not first, convince yourself that the file could actually be opened by hard-coding the name of the file you're trying to open?  `ifstream ist("filename.txt");`.  If you can't open the file that way, then inputting that same name into a string isn't going to work.

Comment: I allowed myself to edit your comments into the question, as this was important information to make the quesiton answerable. If you dont like it, just roll back the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] in the same directory with main.cpp [...]

It does not really matter where you put the input file relative to the source file. 
The file should be in the environment's current working directory when you run the program.

Comment: It's not the executable's path either. It's the environment's _current working directory_ when you run the program.

Answer (score 1):

There must be some confusion in passing argument. You should try to pass absolute path of input file.

Below is your modified application. This will create One test file and use it instead of asking file name for Case 1. For case 2, it use file which doesn't exist.(Delete if present)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
template <typename T> void error(const T &t) { cout << t; }
template <typename T, typename... Args> void error(const T &t, Args... args) {
  cout << t << " ";
  error(args...);
  cout << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  // insert code here...
  // cout << "Plese enter the input file name: " << endl;
  string iname = "a.txt";
  ofstream ofs{iname};
  ofs << 1 << " " << 2 << " " << 3 << " " << 4;
  ofs.close();
  //  cin >> iname;
  // part 1
  {
    cout << "Case1: Reading file a.txt which is just created\n";
    ifstream ist{iname};
    if (!ist)
      error("Can't open input file ", iname);
    if (ist.is_open()) {
      vector<int> numbers;
      int sum = 0;
      int n = 0;
      while (ist >> n) {
        numbers.push_back(n);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i) {
        sum += numbers[i];
      }
      cout << sum << endl;
      ist.close();
    } else {
      error("can't open file to read", iname);
    }
  }
  // part 2
  {
    cout << "Case2:reading file which is not present\n";
    iname = "b.txt";
    std::remove(iname.c_str()); // delete if present
    ifstream ist{iname};
    if (!ist)
      error("Can't open input file ", iname);
    if (ist.is_open()) {
      vector<int> numbers;
      int sum = 0;
      int n = 0;
      while (ist >> n) {
        numbers.push_back(n);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i) {
        sum += numbers[i];
      }
      cout << sum << endl;
      ist.close();
    } else {
      error("can't open file to read", iname);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note: Construct of `std::ifstream` always create object. You need to its object either as you did or `is_open()` method.